# How to specify -? option with GNU getopt

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

When parsing command line arguments with GNU `getopt` command, how do I (if possible) do recognize `-?` as another option? Is there a way to escape it in the opstring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GNU [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) command uses the GNU [getopt()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) library function to
do the parsing of the arguments and options.

The [man page getopt(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) states:

> If getopt() does not recognize an option character, it prints an error
>   message to stderr, stores the character in `optopt`, and returns `?`.
>   The calling program may prevent the error message by setting opterr to
>   0.

Therefore `?` is used to signal "unknown option" and cannot be used as
an option value. (It would be impossible to tell the option `-?` from
an unknown option.)

Comment: At the C level, you can find out if the `?` was real by checking the original string. But apparently GNU `getopt(1)` just eats up the `-?` and returns 1. `getopts` is less confused (except, oddly, in ATT ksh), but doesn't expose the index of the character in the `$OPTIND`th parameter, which means you have to redo a lot of the work if you get a parameter like `-a?b`.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you *could* recognize that as an option string, it would be a really bad idea to use the question mark character as a real argument because most shells use this as part of their glob syntax (representing that the character before it is optionally use or not in the match). Passing a litteral `?` would be difficult for users because they would have to escape it.

If you are creating a help option of some kind the usual syntax is to look for short and long options of `-h` and `--help`.

Comment: If you're using GNU getopt, you should support `--help`.

Comment: Actually, most of the time, `-?` wouldn't match anything and so would be passed literally to the command. But that's fragile (fails if you do have a file called `-a`, or under csh or zsh configured to complain on non-matching globs).

Comment: @cjm: yes. I already do.

Answer (score 1):

To get the effect of using the question mark for **help**, try simply checking to see if the unknown option is indead the question mark character.

For example, I want to print out a message "Unknown option" whenever the unknown option is NOT the question mark.  Next I always call my ***usage*** function.

```
\?) if [ "$OPTARG" != "?" ] ; then echo "Unknown option \"$OPTARG\"" ; fi
        usage
```

In general, I would agree and use the `h` option for help and the `u` option for `usage`, but I had already used those for `host` and `user` and I liked it that way.

PS.  I'm using **bash** on Solaris 10.